# Sorting jpg/pdf files into folders that already exist by name but only using the the first 6 digits

Tags: powershell

I am having issues trying to sort a large amount of files into folders.[Screen shot of files that i need sorted,new files are added daily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqkkz.png)
My main issue is coming from the naming format of the files relative to the folders. Is there a way to move them by the first 6 digits into the corresponding folders that include those digits and if the folder doesn't exist have one created? I couldn't get name-split to work since the beginning of the file name isn't broken up by a break. Does anybody have any code that could do this for me? I'm still learning powershell, not great at writing from scratch yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `String.Substring()` or `String.Remove()` to extract the first 6 digits:

```
$sourceItemFolder = 'C:\unsorted'
$targetRootFolder = 'C:\folder\with\directories'

Get-ChildItem $sourceItemFolder -File |ForEach-Object {
  if($_.Name.Length -ge 6){
    # Extract prefix from file name
    $prefix = $_.Name.Remove(6)

    # Use prefix to find appropriate folder, pick the first match
    $targetFolder = Get-ChildItem $targetRootFolder -Filter "${prefix}*" -Directory |Select -First 1

    if(-not $targetFolder){
        # No matching folder found, create one
        $targetFolder = New-Item -Path $targetRootFolder -Name $prefix -Type Directory 
    }
    # Move the file
    $_ |Move-Item -Destination $targetFolder.FullName
  }
}
```

Comment: Move-Item : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "destination" is null. Change the value of argument
"destination" to a non-null value.
At line:13 char:9
+     $_ |Move-Item -Destination $targetFolder.fullname
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], PSArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Comment: Also what does $SourItemFolder do?

Comment: @TonyMcfarren `$SourItemFolder` was a typo, I've added the conditional folder-creation to the script as well (which caused the error)